# Bold/Normal states for Edittext

Tags: android

For my Edittext, I'm creating the option for the user to be able to set selected text to bold, but the user should also be able to "unbold" the same selected text again.

The functionality for this includes also italic, underline, stroke but will be added on later.

The code that makes the text bold works, but I have no clue about how to unbold the selected text or how to check for if the text is already bold.

```
  CharacterStyle cs;
    int start = editText.getSelectionStart();
    int end = editText.getSelectionEnd();
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new    SpannableStringBuilder(editText.getText());

    switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.bold:


            cs = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
            ssb.setSpan(cs, start, end, 1);
            editText.setText(ssb);
            return true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED with this algorithm found on the web: https://code.google.com/archive/p/droid-writer/

```
int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
int selectionEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();

if (selectionStart > selectionEnd) {
        int temp = selectionEnd;
        selectionEnd = selectionStart;
        selectionStart = temp;
    }


    if (selectionEnd > selectionStart) {
        Spannable str = editText.getText();
        boolean exists = false;
        StyleSpan[] styleSpans;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.bold:
                styleSpans = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, StyleSpan.class);

                // If the selected text-part already has BOLD style on it, then
                // we need to disable it
                for (int i = 0; i < styleSpans.length; i++) {
                    if (styleSpans[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD) {
                        str.removeSpan(styleSpans[i]);
                        exists = true;
                    }
                }

                // Else we set BOLD style on it
                if (!exists) {
                    str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), selectionStart, selectionEnd,
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                }

                editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
                break;
```

Comment: One thing in this is that it will unbold all the line when u try to unbold just one word.

Answer (score 0):

Use accordingly, the codes below are more easier to implement than yours.

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
```

For setting specify text to bold, I found out that build your string using Html is much more easier. For example, if you want some text looks like this

> **1111** neil

You can do this using:

```
String sourceString = "<b>" + id + "</b> " + name; 
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

Comment: How would I use theese on some selected text and not the whole text?

Comment: This isn't helping me or answering my question. I want to be able from the same button to set a selected text to bold and if the selected text already is bold, then it shall be normal again without loosing forexample the italic style if the selected text also contains italic.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm missing your point, can you elaborate more or at least provide a detail example on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Like in microsoft word. You can set the text to bold or italic or a combination of theese styles. Lets say you wrote **HI** in bold, and now i dont want it to be bold anymore, then i select the bolded text and press on  the bold button again to remove the bold effect.