# Make selected text from Edittext Bold and not-bold

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a feature for my app where the user can make a selected text Bold but I also want to make it so that if the selected text is already bold, then the text shall be set to normal again, a kind of an undo-function.

I have tried over 100 of combinations without any succses!

```
    CharacterStyle csBold = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    CharacterStyle csNormal = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
    int start = editText.getSelectionStart();
    int end = editText.getSelectionEnd();
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(editText.getText());
    ssb.setSpan(csBold, start, end, 1);
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb2 = new SpannableStringBuilder(editText.getText());
    ssb2.setSpan(csNormal, start, end, 1);



    switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.bold:

            while(editText.isSelected()){

            if(editText.getSelectionStart() + editText.getSelectionEnd() == ssb.getSpanStart(start) + ssb.getSpanEnd(end)){
                editText.setText(ssb2);
                return true;

            }else{
                editText.setText(ssb);
                return true;

            }

            }
```

Comment: The problem has been  solved and the original solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33835506/5366495

Answer (score 2):

**Update ANSWER**

```
    Edittext editext;
    Button bold_btn , normal_btn , itlac;
   CharacterStyle styleBold  , styleItalc;
   boolean bold = false;

        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                styleBold = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
                styleNormal = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
                styleItalc = new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC);
                underLine = new UnderlineSpan();
                editext = (Editext) findViewById(R.id.editext);
               bold_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
              italic_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
              italic_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
            String wholeText = username.getText().toString();
            int start = username.getSelectionStart();
            int end = username.getSelectionEnd();

            SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(wholeText);

            sb.setSpan(styleItalic, start, end, 0);
            username.setText(sb);
        }
    });
              ........
               .....
               bold_btn.setOnClickListener(BoldbuttonListener);
               normal_btn.setOnClickListener(normalbuttonListener);


    }



            View.OnClickListener BoldbuttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        bold = !bold;

        String wholeText = username.getText().toString();
        int start = username.getSelectionStart();
        int end = username.getSelectionEnd();

        CharacterStyle passedStyle;
        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(wholeText);
        if(bold) {
            passedStyle = styleNormal;


        }else {
            passedStyle = styleBold;

        }
        sb.setSpan(passedStyle, start, end, 0);
        editext.setText(sb);


                    }
                };
```

the same for normal effect

Comment: But I will also make features for Italic, underline, stroke etc. So then I have to make a "normal" button for each feature. 

Lets pretend that I have made a sentence bold and italic and now I want to remove the italic effect, the best way would be to press on italic button again like in Office word.

Comment: I dont need any normal button. The only button that has to be there is for Bold, Italic and Underline. If the selected text already is bold, then if you press again on Bold, it shall make that selected part normal.  If think you're misunderstandig me